# Unescaped Text with th:placeholder

Tags: spring, escaping, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In the current spring-boot / thymeleaf, some of the html views have a form where a field with like this is present:

```
<input type="text" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{account.sobrenome}"/>
```

the value for `account.sobrenome` is placed on file `message.properties`:

```
account.sobrenome=&Uacute;ltimo nome
```

the problem is the application don't resolve the `&Uacute;` to `Ú`. When I use `th:utext`, i have no problems with this.

Anyone know how to use unescaped text with this tag th:placeholder?

Comment: Spring boot, technology created for non latin americans. This is a deficiency of Spring boot when not considering other types of text encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is Spring Message treat `&Uacute` as seperate `&` `U` `a` `c` `u` `t` `e` letters and not as `Ú`.

Change the message to **unicode** as below

```
account.sobrenome=\u00daltimo nome
```

and use

```
th:placeholder="#{account.sobrenome}"
```

Comment: If using others charset like latin iso or utf8, etc the unicode value is not same visible character. It is a bad practice. Use the Standar and the HTML Entities.